# How do I send a TAB using Perl's Net::Telnet?

Tags: perl, telnet

I am using Perl's [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Telnet) module to access an application available over telnet.

I am using `$telnet->waitfor()` and `$telnet->print()` methods to determine the form received and submit appropriate data. One of the forms has two options - "Find" and "Cancel".

In a terminal, I can just hit TAB to choose "Cancel" and ENTER. But within the script, sending TAB is not working for me, i.e.:

```
$telnet->print('\t')
```

or

```
$telnet->print("\t")
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: $telnet->print("\t") should work, why don't you post a little more info?

Comment: Assalam Alaikum Osama, You are right, $telnet->print("\t") is working.

Answer (score 2):

To send a tab, you need to send the actual bits that represent the tab. The single-quoted version, `'\t'` won't do that. To turn `\t` from it's logical form to the right bit representation, you need the double-quote interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $telnet->print("\t") is working.